# Hex Values Get Weird After 127

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, hex

I'm trying to display all of the hex characters from 0-255. I'm able to represent binary data from 0x00 to 0x7f, but once i get above 0x7f it looks like it's doing some type of UTF formatting, and starts adding C's. Here is how I'm doing this"

```
unichar value = 0;

for (value = 0; value < 255; value++) {

    [test writeExample:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", value]];
}
```

Does anyone know how to change this to have it keep displaying proper hex after 0x7f? I've tried char with %c, and unichar with %C. I've been able to represent 0x00 - 0x7f but I've been unable to represent the extended ascii characters 0x80 - 0xFF.

Comment: Yes sir, %X didn't work.

Comment: What do you get when you try `NSLog(@"%X", 255);`? By the way, your for loop ends before you get to 255, which is a valid hex (FF).

Comment: And, when I plug %X into the above loop, it just keeps going and going and going.

Comment: This is almost a repeat of your previous question. Again, split the line into two. `NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", value];` and `[test writeExample:val];`. This way you can see which line is the problem.

Comment: What do you want to send to your `writeExample:` method? Using `%x` gives you the hex representation of each integer value. Using `%C` gives you the character representation for each integer value. Two very different results.

Comment: @rmaddy I've already done that. It works great, prints hex just fine up until 0x7f. From there it prints gibberish, so I decided to make it a new question since it's a new issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question because I'm not seeing the problem here. Can you post your `writeExample:` method? Every time I run `%x` I'm getting exactly what I expect; it's `%c` that's giving me upside down question marks and other special ASCIIs.

Comment: @OralB You really need to clarify your issue. Using `%x` in the string format and using `NSLog` to log the results shows the proper hex values. As with your previous question, you are very unclear and you leave out the important details of your mystery `writeExample:` method.

Comment: As I said earlier, it turns to gibberish after 127. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon my understanding of your question and the [Apple Dev Docs on String Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), the proper string formatter to use in the case of representing an integer as a hex value is to use the formatter `%x`. End of story.

The problem seems to be lying in your `writeExample:` method. So perhaps you should try a method similar to the following:

```
- (void)writeExample:(unichar)value
{
    NSLog(@"0x%02x", value);
}
```

It may not be perfect but at least it's a starting point. That will print a hex representation.

If you want to send it through as a string, you can; just change the method to:

```
- (void)writeExample:(NSString*)value
{
    unichar val = [value intValue];
    NSLog(@"0x%02x", val);
}
```

and send the string with format `%d` instead of `%c`:

```
[test writeExample:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value]];
```

Without further details, this is the best answer I can give you. If you provide more details, then I will gladly edit my answer to help you figure out exactly what is going on.

Comment: Why are you dividing `value` by 256?

Comment: Because if it's over 255, (for example 256), it should be 1x00, right? or am I wrong? I have a limited knowledge of hex...

Comment: If hex cannot go over 255, then it would just be `NSLog(@"0x%02x", value);`

Comment: Who knows? The OP is doing a terrible job of describing their requirement. But in general, the hex value of decimal 256 is simply 100. It may also be represented as 0x100. What you have is a format I've never seen.

Comment: @rmaddy There that should print proper hex.

Comment: Just one huge problem left - in the OP's code, they are passing an `NSString` to the `writeExample:` method, not a `unichar`.

Comment: @rmaddy I guess what I was trying to do was save that step. From what he did provide, he is converting the unichar to a string before sending it. Why not just send it as is? I can rewrite the method to convert the string back to a unichar, but that seems silly, IMO.

Comment: @rmaddy I added the method that accepts strings, but it's pointless to cast it back and forth.

Comment: @OralB It's not a question of being ignorant or not, it's a case of being very unclear. I still have no idea what your issue is for this or your previous question. You simply don't provide the proper details needed to help.